# Filter 2 arrays to see if there is a duplicate

Tags: javascript, typescript

Im wondering how you compare 2 arrays to see weather or not there is a duplicate within that array

```
 const result = this.specialRange.filter(d => !dayMonth.includes(d));
```

What ive tried just returns the entire array back to me which i dont want I just want to see is there a duplicate yes -> do something no -> Dont

```
   var dayMonth: any[] = ["1201","1202","1203","1204",1205"];
   specialRange: any[] = ["1201","1202","1203","1204"];
```

It either returns the entire special range or daymonth depending what the leading argument is I just want a simple true/false equivalent if there is a duplicate

Both arrays are formatted to have similar values despite being of type Any
This is just for practical learning purposes at the moment

the values always follow something like "1201,1202,1203,1204" So MM/DD

Edit for Pyth:

On test:

dayMonth = `1215,1216`

specialRange = `1215,1216,1217,1218,1219,1220,1221,1222,1223,1224,1225,1226,1227,1228,1229`

Adapted method:

```
for(let v of dayMonth){
      if(this.specialRange.includes(v)){
        alert('true');
      }
      else{
        alert('false')
      }

    }
```

Result => False/False

for some reason my console doesnt log anything when I use console.log

Comment: You have typed these as `any[]` but what type is actually in there? The question is how you determine equality.

Comment: I make sure the arrays have the same values Which are always something like "1201,1202,1203,1204"

Comment: when you use `any`. What is the point of using typescript?

Comment: There is none currently its just figuring the logic then ill asign the types its a bit of a backwards way of doing it but I confuse my self otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no doubt that there are better ways to do this, but here's a quick and dirty way:

```js
const a1 = [1200, 1201, 1202, 1203];
const a2 = [1202, 1203, 1204];
// Expected Duplicates: [1202, 1203]
// Expected Unique: [1200, 1201, 1204]


function filter_duplicates(arr1, arr2) {
  let duplicates = [];
  let unique = [];
  for (let v of arr1) {
    // If value in arr2 it's a duplicate, if not, it's unique
    if (arr2.includes(v)) {
        duplicates.push(v);
    } else {
        unique.push(v);
    }
  }
  for (let v of arr2) {
    // If value isn't a duplicate, it's unique
    if (!duplicates.includes(v)) {
      unique.push(v);
    }
  }
  console.log("Duplicates: ", duplicates);
  console.log("Unique: ", unique);
  return {duplicates: duplicates, unique: unique}
}
filter_duplicates(a1, a2);
```

Comment: I think it is too much verbose. You can simply use filter() function, like @shalini has described.

Comment: @ManedWolf yes, you're right. I'm sorry, I haven't used JS in a while.

Comment: @pythag0ras_updated the question just used what I thought was needed but results are returning false Im very confused

Comment: Nevermind resolved I was being silly I had the special range in an array like this: 

"1201,1202,1203" and daymonth in an array like "1202","1203"

Answer (score 2):

```
let result = this.specialRange.filter(o1 => dayMonth.some(o2 => o1 === o2));
```

This will results into duplicate items ..you can simply check length of result array ..if array.length > 0 then return true else false

Comment: See issue is with this, I still get a length of 0 despite there being duplicate values

Comment: Why use `some` instead of `includes`?